# Two render bodies in layout page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I understand that only 1 RenderBody can exist in the MVC3 layout page however I want to attempt to create another. Maybe I'm looking at it the wrong way... Ideally I want to add a testimonial section that pulls in from the DB and display 1 testimonial at a time and a different 1 for each page refresh or new page. What is the best way to go about this?

Controller

```
CategoryDBContext db = new CategoryDBContext();
public ActionResult Testimonial(int id)
    {
        TestimonialModel model = db.Testimonials.Find(id);
        return View(model);
    }
```

Model

```
public class TestimonialModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<TestimonialModel> Testimonials { get; set; }
}
```

The View is in a folder called CategoryData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `@Html.Action()`

Here is a great blog post about using them: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/html-action-and-html-renderaction-in-Asp-Net-mvc/

This would allow you to have a `TestimonialController` that can take in values, query for data and return a partial view.

Answer (score 3):

You need to be use:

Layout:

```
@RenderSection("Testimonial", false) @*false means that this section is not required*@
```

and in you View

```
@section Testimonial{
}
```

Comment: How does the controller know where to look for the @section Testimonial? I'm updating my question with what I have so far...

Comment: @bl4kh4k you controller doesn't know anything about sections .. how do you wanna refresh testimonials?

Comment: The DB has say about 5 entries, the idea is to display 1 at a time in the view, so if somebody refreshed the page, I'd like to have a random entry display.

Comment: I looked at an example of rendersection and the section is defined in the view portion of the site... this would mean I'd have to put the same section in every view? Isn't there an easier way?

Comment: @bl4kh4k is your testimonial on every page?